# Magento search results in wrong order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm working on a Magento 1.9.1.0 project and the search results aren't being displayed in the correct order. I've modified a function to fetch the results in order of position (which almost works), but it appears to be looping through each category first, listing the products from that category in order of position and name and then moving on to the next category - for example, if I search "a":

Anti-Slip Bath Mat, Bath Safety Strips, Square Shower Mat, Walking Frame, (here the order breaks, because it's entered a new category) Alarm Clock, Amplified Phone.

I'd have liked it to have returned:

Alarm Clock, Amplified Phone, Bath Safety Strips, Square Shower Mat, Walking Frame, Anti-Slip Bath Mat

(Anti-Slip Bath Mat would be last, because the position of everything else is 0 where as this product has a position of 10).

Is there a way I can amend this search just display all products without ordering them in category order? The function I'd written to achieve what I have so far is:

```
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders = array_merge(array(
        'relevance' => $this->__('Relevance'),
        'name' => $this->__('Name'),
        'position' => $this->__('Position')
    ), $availableOrders);

    $this->getListBlock()
        ->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders)
        ->setDefaultDirection('asc')
        ->setSortBy('position');
    return $this;

}
```

and...

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }

return $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('position')->addAttributeToSort('name');

}
```

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve is to sort products by a custom attribute called "pay_in_store", but the results seem to spit out the first category of results in the correct order and then the results from that category that don't have the option "pay_in_store" checked. Then it jumps to the next category and does the same. I don't want this on a per-category basis - I just need all products emptying into the results.

Answer (score 0):

add below code your local.xml or in your any layout.xml file

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
 <reference name="search_result_list">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
    <action method="setSortBy"><param>attribute_you_want_to_use</param></action>
 </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Comment: I tried this originally but it doesn't sort the entire result in order of position.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to sort products by a custom attribute called "pay_in_store", but the results seem to spit out the first category of results in the correct order and then the results from that category that don't have the option "pay_in_store" checked. Then it jumps to the next category and does the same. I don't want this on a per-category basis - I just need all products emptying into the results.

Comment: In app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php in function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray(), add $options = array('position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),'name'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name')); in above code add attribute name between <param>.